# Delegate event binding to outside tree

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a widget whose behavior requires listening to events bubbled to the document object.  However, this widget is dynamically injected and removed from the DOM.

My concern with "straight-up" event binding on the document is that after the widget is removed, the binding still exists.  At that point, I imagine the handler's reference to the widget will prevent it from getting GC'd.

I'm using an approach now that involves using a singleton handler on the document along with closure-scoped array of widget references.  I then listen for the DOM node removal event to update the array when widgets are removed from the DOM.

It works well but it's a little unwieldy, and I'm not sure about the extent of node-removal event support.

Does jQuery have an event binding form like `.delegate()`, but whose selector applies to another node's hierarchy?

Comment: Do you mean the event delegation syntax of `.on()`?

Comment: @j08691 That only allows listening to events that occur within the selected element's own hierarchy: the selected element itself and its descendents.  I wish to listen to events elsewhere in the DOM.